# Behavior of execstack flag

Tags: gcc, stack, flags

I'm working with gcc 7.5 and I can't find information about the flag -z,noexecstack in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/gcc/
Where can I find information about its behavior?, i.e. is it enabled by default, how to check that it is applied to my files and so on.

I found https://linux.die.net/man/8/execstack and it says *"The marking is done automatically by recent GCC versions"* since version 7.5 was released in Nov 2019 I'm assuming this apply for gcc 7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [link options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> -z keyword
>
> -z is passed directly on to the linker along with the keyword keyword. See the section in the documentation of your linker for permitted values and their meanings.

From [man ld](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

> ```
> -z keyword
>     The recognized keywords are:
>     [...]
>     execstack 
>     Marks the object as requiring executable stack.
>     [...]
>     noexecstack 
>     Marks the object as not requiring executable stack.
> ```